# Displaying just one post from each category on archive page

Tags: categories

My categories look like this. Each has one or more posts

```
-Main Category
--Main Category Sub-category 1
--- 1 post here
--- 1 post here
--Main Category Sub-category 2
--- 1 post here
--- 1 post here
--- 1 post here
--Main Category Sub-category 3
--- 1 post here
```

When viewing Main Category archive page I only want the first post from each of the subcategories. So in my case I would only have 3 posts. Using twentythirteen theme. Don't want to change too much. I hope it can be done with query_posts.

```
        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php query_posts($query_string . '&??????'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content-category', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `query_posts()` use the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class instead... the link to the Codex will also reference all the appropriate query parameters.

The following would query the most recent post in a particular category, you will need to define the `$category_id`

```
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat' => $category_id, 'posts_per_page' => 1 );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content-category', get_post_format() );
    }
} 

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: ok ... but that only returns one post. I was trying to return one post from each sub-category.

Comment: You didn't say how far along you were. You'll need to use `get_categories()` and run a `foreach()` loop.